# Slow integration for simple functions involving `UnitBox`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I would like to integrate periodic functions involving step functions. For example,

```
f[x_] = UnitBox[1 - Mod[x, 3]]
int[x_] := Integrate[f[u], {u, -x, x}]
intn[x_] := NIntegrate[f[u], {u, -x, x}]
```

Computing `int[20]` or `intn[20]` takes 0.06 seconds, plotting `Plot[int[x], {x, 2, 10}]` or `Plot[intn[x],{x,2,10}]` about 6 seconds. Changing `UnitBox` to `HeavisidePi` made things much worse, probably because the latter is not a monovalued function.

When combining such functions, it quicky takes too much time to be usable. However, from basic geometry, the integral can be computed quite easily. So my question is whether it is possible to reduce the computation time. Possibilities could i) deal with the singular points, ii) take advantage of the piecewise-constant property of `f`, iii) use periodicity. For iii), one workaround would be to modify the boundaries of the integral to an interval of span at most the period, and add the number of periods times the integral over one period, but I am hoping for a more straightfoward solution, if possible.

Another slightly less trivial example:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] = 
  UnitBox[0.5` - 1.25` (3.` - Mod[x, 3.`])] + 
   UnitBox[0.5` - 1.25` Mod[x, 3.`]];
u[x_, t_] := NIntegrate[psitilde[xi], {xi, x - t, x + t}]
Plot[{u[x, 1.3]}, {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The `Plot` takes about 20s, plus it throws convergence errors (that's understandable) and the graph is hence "noisy".
+6

**Edit** As pointed out by yarchik,

```
i[x_] = Integrate[f[u], u] /. {u -> x}
Plot[{i[x] - i[-x]}, {x, 2, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

takes 0.02s and

```
Plot[{(Integrate[f[u], u] /. {u -> x}) - (Integrate[f[u], 
  u] /. {u -> -x})}, {x, 2, 10}]
```

takes 1.3s.

However, both curves are discontinuous.

Comment: Evaluating `int[20]` takes far longer (1.4s) on my machine (macOS Mathematica11) while `intn[20]` gives a warning: `NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.`

Comment: @Sascha Yes, because I had used `HeavisidePi` instead of `UnitBox`. Edited.

Comment: `Plot[Integrate[f[u], u] /. {u -> x}, {x, 2, 10}, PlotRange -> All] // Timing` takes only half a second...

Comment: @yarchik Interesting, added a few words in the question about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea:  Add singularities to integration iterator of `NIntegrate`:

```
i2[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  f[u], {u, -x, Sequence @@ Range[1/2 + Ceiling[-x - 1/2], x], x}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 3}, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> If[Abs[x] < 1, 15, Infinity]];
```

The `Method` option settings assume `f[x]` is piecewise linear (or a low degree polynomial).  Remove `"Points"` and possibly `"SymbolicProcessing"` if needed.

```
Plot[i2[x], {x, 2, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Second idea: It's like @yarchik's idea, but using `DSolve`.  You have to know what range of inputs you would like to have before running `DSolve`:

```
if = y /. First@DSolve[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, -10, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.161635, Null}  *)

Plot[if[x] - if[-x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`DSolve` returns a `Piecewise` function, which leads `Plot` to poke holes in the graph.  Use `Exclusions -> None` to remove them.  (It plots faster, too.)

Comment: I get errors when I use `i2[x]` whether I use `"Points" -> 3` and `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`, although it generates a plot that appears correct. The `DSolve` solution works great!

Comment: @JackLaVigne What version are you using?  I get none in V10.4.1, on rechecking with a fresh kernel. (Thanks for letting me know, in any case.)

Comment: I was using version 11.0. I re-ran using version 10.4.1.0 and got no errors. There is progress for you :)

Comment: @JackLaVigne I added `?NumericQ` protection.  Maybe that'll help.  Normally I would've done that, but I was following the OP's lead.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.