# Strange side-effect of infinite $MaxPiecewiseCases

Tags: numerical-integration

In investigating [Slow integration for simple functions involving `UnitBox`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125530/36788), I defined

```
f[x_] = UnitBox[1 - Mod[x, 3]]
intn[x_] := NIntegrate[f[u], {u, -x, x}]
```

I evaluated

```
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = ∞}, intn[20]]
```

and received the following errors/warnings, and the correct answer.  (I realise that in this case, modifying `$MaxPiecewiseCases` is not needed to evaluate the `intn`.)

[image]

I see similar behaviour in both V10.4 and V11.0.0 (Linux Mint 17.3).

Does anyone have any clues as to what is happening?

Comment: You may wish to flag this as a bug and report it to Wolfram, Inc.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment plus a work-around (at least, for the specific functions in the question).  According to its documentation, the value of `$MaxPiecewiseCases` can impact such functions as `PiecewiseExpand`, `FunctionExpand`, `Reduce`, and `Integrate`. The documentation makes no mention of `NIntegrate`, although clearly it has an impact on it.  With

```
$Version
(* 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016) *)

Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, intn[20]]
```

produces the same results presented in the question.  Unexpectedly,

```
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, PiecewiseExpand[intn[20]]]
```

produces the set of error messages twice.  (I would have expected only one set of error messages.)  Limiting the arguments of `f` and `intn` to be numerical has no impact on either case.

On the other hand,

```
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, PiecewiseExpand[f[x], -40 < x < 40]]
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, Reduce[f[x] == x, x]]
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, FunctionExpand[f[100]^2]]
```

and

```
intn[x_] := Integrate[f[u], {u, -x, x}]
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, intn[20]]
(* 27/2 *)
```

work well.  Even

```
intn[x_] := NIntegrate[f[u], {u, -x, x}, Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = Infinity}, intn[20]]
(* 13.5168 *)
```

and Monte Carlo variants work, although not very accurately.  So, it appears that only `NIntegrate` with certain `Method`s generates error messages before returning the correct answer.

Evidently, if `Integrate` can handle the integrand, it should be used.